# Android Camera Preview showing corner images

Tags: android, android-camera

I am creating an application where I want to restrict the camera preview to about 80% of camera screen. I could accomplish it using the layout_weight=0.8 . Now I need to implement border at the corner of the camera preview.

I have attached a snapshot of what I really want to accomplish. The borders shown in red color is what I really want . Any pointer will be helpful.

[image]

Here is how I have reduced camera image to 80%.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center"
android:weightSum="1.0">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/surfaceparent"
    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1.0">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">
    </SurfaceView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the surfaceview in a relative layout and add images over it:

```
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/surfaceparent"
    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1.0">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">
    </SurfaceView>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/tl" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/tr" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
   <ImageView android:src="@drawable/bl" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
   <ImageView android:src="@drawable/br" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you could have one 9 patch image

Comment: If I do this I cannot see my camera preview. I only able to see images.

Comment: Apologies, I switched the LinearLayout in your xml to RelativeLayout and added the ImageViews without looking at the other bits.. RelativeLayouts dont allow weight, so layout_height for the surfaceview needs to be fill_parent

Comment: But then fill_parent for layout_height extends the camera preview to full height which is not correct. If want height to be lesser than parent. Width is correct but height is a problem.